# IE9 not removing :hover style on DOM change

Tags: css, internet-explorer, dom, internet-explorer-9, hover

I am trying to make a button that has a :hover state on a popup box, when you one of the buttons I am removing the box from the DOM and saving it for future interacts. the problem is when I reattach it to the DOM in IE9 it has not cleared the :hover state until you next hover it then mouse out.

Obviously this is not present on any other browser, but is reproducible here: http://jsfiddle.net/5dXSp/

I cant find a manual way of clearing a css :hover state, and I really dont want to have to rebuild the menu every time because of this. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't quite understood it. The button should be black after moving to another position, where it didn't have the mouse hovered, but nonetheless should have the :hover-state applied? If you re-attach an element it of course isn't hovered.

Comment: the problem is that when I move it the :hover-state is still applied (in this case black) and I want it to be back to the un-hovered state (grey) as the mouse is no longer hovering the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try controlling the hover with a class and jQuery. This seemed to work for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/5dXSp/25/

CSS:

```
.box{
    height:200px;
    margin:10px 0;
}    
.button{
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    height:20px;  
    background:#ccc;      
}
.hover {
  background-color: #000;
 }​
```

jQuery:

```
$(".button").hover(
  function () {
   $(this).addClass("hover");
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
  }
);

$(".button").click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $(ev.target).appendTo($(".catch"));
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, though I was hoping for a less intrusive approach with the javascript, the less I have to play with class names the better, that is what the css psudo-classes are there for after all!

Comment: Seems to be the only way to do this, still a shame though.

Answer (score 2):

There is one additional way to fix it.
You can hide element before detaching it from DOM, but *in a different event processing*.
Something like that:

```
// HTML structure: <div id="aaa"> <a id="bbb"> Text </a> </div>

var bbb = document.getElementById('bbb');
var container = document.getElementById('aaa');

bbb.attachEvent("onclick", function() {
    bbb.style.display = "none";

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        container.removeChild(bbb);
        bbb.style.display = "";

        // Some time later

        window.setTimeout(function() {
            container.appendChild(bbb);
        }, 2000);
    }, 1);
});
```

bbb.style.visibility = "hidden" worked too.

Comment: Thanks, this was a good solution that worked for me.  I didn't want to have to restructure my CSS+JS just because IE9 is brain dead.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery you can do ugly things like:

```
if($.browser.msie)
   $('el').html($(el).html());
```

to de and attach the element