# Internet Explorer :Hover style getting stuck on jQuery sortable element

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, jquery-ui-sortable

So I have a UL with jquery-sortable LI's below it.  Each LI has a :Hover CSS style associated with it.  The problem comes when I drag an LI away from the UL and let go, the Hover effect is still applied in IE9 (chrome works fine).

HTML

```
<ul id="test">
<li>test</li>
<li>test 2</li>
</ul>​
```

CSS

```
#test li:hover{
background-color:Yellow;}​
```

Javascript

```
$("#test").sortable();​
```

See Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hBhZD/2/

I have seen the following SO question:
[IE9 not removing :hover style on DOM change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388416/ie9-not-removing-hover-style-on-dom-change) .
Which seems to be the same issue I am experiencing, but I want to avoid using jQuery to force the style changes, if possible.

Anyone know how to fix this with CSS?

Comment: If you are already using jQuery, why do you not want to use it to fix it?

Comment: A fair question. I want to use the functionality present in CSS (:hover) for styling my page, instead of adding the additional overhead involved with running a script to take care of styling.  Not to mention the improved readability and maintainability of the CSS approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `helper` option to clone the object while dragging; doing this forces IE8 to redraw the object once released and so reset the hover state.

```
$("#test").sortable({
    helper: 'clone'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research and the lack of CSS based answers I've found, it seems this IE bug is insurmountable with pure CSS (if anyone has found otherwise, please prove me wrong!).  Here is the jQuery based workaround I used (in case you're wondering):

```
function toggleTabHover(tabName, hoverStatus) {
    var element = $('#'+tabName);

    if (element.hasClass('selectedTab')) {
        return;
    }

    if (hoverStatus === "on") {
        element.addClass('tabHoverOn');
        element.removeClass('tabHoverOff');
    }
    else {
        element.addClass('tabHoverOff');
        element.removeClass('tabHoverOn');
    }
}
```

You pass in the name of the tab to hover over and the 'on'/'off' state you want to switch to.  The selectedTab class is for a tab that has been clicked on (I don't want the hover affect being applied to the active tab).